# Handling ASP.NET Core Web API object property binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API application. If I send to API endpoint empty quotes as json object property value in request body I`ll have that property been initialized with null (it is of type Guid?). How can I change such behavior? What I need is just send BadRequest (400) as response error code.

That is an endpoint:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ExampleResponse>> ExamplePatch([FromBody] ExampleModel exampleModel,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    /* At this point exampleModel.ExampleGuid is initilized with null. So it should be handled before */
    /* some processing */
    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created, ExampleResponse);
}
```

Here is the model:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "9.10.53.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0)")]
public class ExampleModel 
{
    /* a bunch of properties here */
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("exampleGuid", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public System.Guid? ExampleGuid { get; set; }
}
```

Json from request body:

```
{ ... other parameters here ..., "exampleGuid": "" }
```

I have one restriction on that - I cannot add attributes to that model property or change the model somehow. I`ll be very appreciated for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Validator for the ExampleModel with FluentValidation package.
Here is the example:

```
public class ExampleModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ExampleModel>
    {
        public ExampleModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(e => e.ExampleGuid)
                .Must(guid => guid.ToString().lenght > 0)
                 .When(e => e.ExampleGuid.HasValue)
                 .WithMessage("Must be a valid GUID");

        }
    }
```

This will validate your model before the endpoint body.

Additionaly I personally like to add this piece of code in my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            
            .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ExampleModelValidator>())
            .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
            {
                options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
                {
                    var errorsList = string.Join(" | ", context.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(err => err.ErrorMessage).ToArray());
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult(errorsList);
                };
            });
    }
```

This will return all validation messages separated by pipe and BadRequest as response.

Comment: But in ConfigureServices you should call AddMvc to use AddFluentValidation and ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions doesn`t exists in asp.net core 2.1.
I have tried FluentValidation but Guid? can be null, it is correct use-case. But sending empty quotes is incorrect and should be responded with 400 error code.

Comment: AddMvc should not make you any problems I am using that too. ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions  is for me convinient to get all errors separated with pipe but you also can go without that. About null, you can also check if it is not empty string if it is not null, I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I figured out that straightforward way to do such validation or custom model binding is to create custom IModelBinder and IModelBinderProvider (https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) where I can put a validation logic. And I can use filters or/and just parse raw json from HttpContext. But even better will be change open api spec to be more corresponding to the requirements and nswag could generate much correct code with proper constraint attributes.